# Drupal full database limit

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, memory-limit

I made a drupal site and my client decide to go with shared hosting ( 1nor1 ). They gave unlimited MySQL databases. The maximum of the database it's 1GB. I reached it, and the only thing I can make it's clean the cache and accesslog tables ( 100-200MB ), but after 3-4 days when accesslog and cache tables get those 100-200MB the page crashes once more time.

I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897260/how-to-deal-with-the-200mb-limit-of-godaddy-database but the answer it's change hosting provider what I can't do.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: If your current hosting provider won't give you more resources, you'll have to change hosting providers. I'm not sure what else you expect anyone to be able to say. 200mb was a pathetically small amount of space for a database 5/10 years ago, let alone today. My advice is move to a proper host and don't look back.

Comment: No. I have 1GB limit and all i can do it's delete the cache tables that has 100-200MB, so the database will move from 800MB to 1024MB. And what I say it's I can't change the hosting provider because is from my client that paid it already.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. The answer is the same though, if your database isn't big enough, get a bigger database. If your hosting provider won't give you one, get a new hosting provider. The other option is truncating your data, which I'm gonna guess is not a viable one. Short of rewriting how Drupal stores its data to compress it somehow, you don't have an alternative

Answer (score 0):

A few things can be factors in your *database size increasing rapidly*.

1. If you are storing file uploads in your database - store them in the filesystem instead
2. The Statistics module - disable it
3. Database logging (dblog/watchdog) - disable it

You could also have a large volume of comments or/registered users. Try checking those two area's for spam as well and disable both.